# "Flattening" two shapefiles together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I have this big land use map. I extracted shapes associated with mountains so that I can improve the classification (for example, I corrected clouds in the mountains to be forest, among other things). Now I want to flatten the two layers with the extracted layer over-writing the info on the original map. I tried union, merge and other things, but the info I want overwritten is still there (ex. the clouds are still there).

I checked for instance the result of the union and I saw that the all the data columns of both shapefiles were appended together. The effect I want is for the data of the top layer to replace the data of the lower layer. In Photoshop, this is just basic flattening (i.e. pixel value of higher layer replaces all pixel values of underlying layers).

Comment: Have you tried the Update tool (requires an Advanced license)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an Advanced license.

Comment: I think the tool that you would ideally use is Erase but this requires an Advanced license.  However, with a Basic license you can easily achieve the same result. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80376/how-to-select-inverse-of-intersection-of-two-polygon-layers/80380#80380 is a Q&A where how to do this has been mentioned.

Comment: If you remember the selection rules you used to make the subsets you can simply save the non-exported rows to an additional file and append that to the edited subsets.

Comment: see also the free version of ET geowizard for an Erase tool

Comment: Is the original land use map in raster format, or polygons?

Comment: Did you make any changes to the geometry, or just the attributes? If the geometry is the same, why not just use a Select by Location (or Select Layer by Location) to select all of the polys in the original file using the updated file and delete them, then Append the revised polys into the original data set?

Comment: Hello everyone! Thanks for your answers. Ultimately the answer of GISGe below (i.e. union-->erase after using select by attributes-->merge) got me what I want. I am also curious exploring Vince's suggestion.  

I really appreciate all your inputs. Arigatou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have an Advanced license:

1. Union the old and the updated polygons.
2. Select the features having FIDs from both input feature classes and delete them.
3. Merge the updated feature class with the output of the previous step.

Comment: Union is overkill when all the geometries and most of the attributes are the same.

Comment: Prior to union (limited to two feature classes in basic and standard) use the integrate tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000 to "snap" little mismatches together.